# Is .lower() with day is necessary on this url?

Tags: django, testing, django-models, django-testing

https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com/blob/master/blog/models.py#L77

Is putting .lower() with day is necessary? What does day do with the .lower()?

Comment: It's likely a result of copy/paste? https://github.com/django/djangoproject.com/commit/4ec27e1033728e16258fca3548e1037f27152d13

Comment: Ohh so djangoproject having good code is copy pasting?

Comment: Maybe ask Jannis Leidel directly what his two-year old problem is.

Comment: I suspect djangoproject.com has far fewer eyes on it than Django itself. Issue a PR and you'll get an answer!